# Rules: How to access field values by language

Tags: 7, entities, rules, i18n-l10n

I have content in two languages (entity translation). If I want to use it's field values in PHP, I can access them by code like this:

```
$node->field_name['en'][0]['value']
```

or

```
field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_name', 'en')
```

But Rules load only currently active language. How to access field value in particular language in Rules data selectors?

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach loop for field_name['und']['value']

Comment: Hello. Could you add a bit more commentary, or a code sample. Your answer is probably right, but it's the case "**I** know what **I** mean" - other users, especially ones with little experience, may find your answer hardly useful at all.

Comment: It seems you did not understand my question. I am asking how to access values by language in Rules, not in code.